# Not able to insert Value in Redis

Tags: java, html, redis

This is a bit simple question but I am struggling for an 2 hours so I thought it might be better to ask for help.
I want to read values from a properties file through java program and dump in to `redis` using `jedis`.

Property files contain value that contain single qoutes eg:

```
welcomemsg='hi\n'
```

basically, an html file,
But single quotes are not inserted and also slashes.
I tried escaping slashes and quotes eg:

`\'hi\\\n'` etc..

but it did not help.
I tried searching google but was not able to find any topics which could point me in a right direction.
If I can get any advice it will be great !!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this code works fine

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
jedis.set("foo", "\'hi\\n\'");
String value = jedis.get("foo");
System.out.println(value);
```

And on redis CLI

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get foo
"'hi\\n'"
```

Comment: Thanks !!!It helped!!!The problem was in application!After trying this I debuged whole application and found It was manipulating String somewhere!!:)